# Move files with a condition in Python

Tags: python, move, shutil

I need to move files from one folder to another based on a given condition. The condition is that if a certain file has more than or equal to 100 rows (for example), it will be moved to another folder.

I've tried different versions of shutil however, I have been unsuccessful with moving any files at all.

```
src = 'path1'
dest = 'path2'

for files in src.glob('*.csv'):
   df = pd.read_csv(files)
   if len(df) >= 100:
      shutil.move(src, os.path.join(dest, files))
```

or

```
src = 'path1'
dest = 'path2'

for files in src.glob('*.csv'):
   if len(files) >= 100:
      shutil.move(src, os.path.join(dest, files))
```

I would like to know why it's not working at all. It seems pretty much straightforward with the shutil command.

*Updated the code above from the comments*. All still don't work at all.

** Funny I get down points for an honest question. I'm new to python and I'm struggling to code. This isn't a nice community as far as my experience.

Comment: There are no files like `'\*.csv'`, so your loop executes correctly for each of the zero matched files. Try `'*.csv'` instead.

Comment: if `df = pd.read_csv` then `df` is the read function itself, not a dataframe you'd get by calling it. And `len(df)` would crash. [ask] and [mre]

Comment: for files in output_dir.glob('\*.csv'):
   df = pd.read_csv   #  Here df is a function, not a file  -> pd.read_csv(filepath)

Comment: Thanks for pointing all these out. I've adjusted the code. Unfortunately, it still wouldn't work.

Comment: `len(files)` would be the length of the file name. And you probably don't want to move `src`, the entire directory.

Comment: @Amadan I still don't understand why it doesn't work when I use `len(df)`. And isn't it, since I'm calling a dataframe, it should read `len(df)` as the number of rows?

Comment: @XiaominWu I have changed it to `pd.read_csv(files)` but it still wouldn't work

Comment: Why don't you check if the control is entering the `if block` using a simple print statement?
Try to print the `os.path.join(dest, files)` part too.

Edit: what is output_dir.glob(...)?

Comment: @ChitturiSaiSuman I think the problem is with the if statement. The `os.path.join(dest, files)` is okay. I'm not so sure how to frame the `if condition` so it counts the number of rows of each file and check if it is greater than or equal to 100.

Comment: @solo1111, Can you try using `df.shape[0]` instead of `len(df)`?
I found this here - https://datascienceparichay.com/article/get-the-number-of-rows-in-a-pandas-dataframe/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `df.shape[0]` instead of `len(df)` to check the number of rows (excluding header).

`len(df)` must be avoided, since it also includes the header in the count.

Edit: files must be appended to src, not only to dest.

So, the move statement changes to `shutil.move(os.path.join(src, files), os.path.join(dest, files))`

Comment: Thank you so much! This explains why it is not moving any files to the destination folder. I'm really learning from you and @XiaominWu

Answer (score 2):

`pd.read_csv` is a function, `df = pd.read_csv` just assigns the function to `df`, not the csv file content. You should call the function and pass the file name as parameter to read the csv file content. So you should change `df = pd.read_csv` to `df = pd.read_csv(files)`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. However, I'm not sure why it still doesn't work at all

Answer (score 1):

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd
import shutil

src = Path('./')
dest = Path('./ttt/')

for files in src.glob('*.csv'):
    print(files)
    df = pd.read_csv(files)
    if len(df) >= 100:
        shutil.move(files, dest / files.name)  # the src of move should be files, not your src
```

Comment: this works on my local machine.

Comment: This works! Thank you so so much! Now I understand! I think I was a bit confused with `shutil` as I've been calling out the filename instead of the file source/filepath!